# Type '()" does not confirm to protocol: 'BooleanType'

Tags: swift, swift-playground

Having difficulty, ound some articles / questions asking this but it wasn't exactly what it was.

```
var catMoves = 0
let maxCatMoves = 8
func catOutOfMoves() {
    if catMoves = maxCatMoves {
        var aliveCat = 0
    }} //do something
else {//do something else}
```

Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: () is just a Void type so, it does not conform to any protocol. What is it that you exactly want to do ?

Comment: Im making it so the "Cat" (computer) has limited moves (8) once those moves have all been used (all 8) the cat is terminated/despawns

Comment: `if catMoves = maxCatMoves` should be `if catMoves == maxCatMoves`. Use `==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement is not closed properly

```
func catOutOfMoves() {
        if catMoves = maxCatMoves {
            var aliveCat = 0
            //do something
        } 
       else {
          //do something else
        }
    }
```

Comment: Should be `if catMoves == maxCatMoves`.

Comment: @DanielStorm actually both are correct....i kept assignment operator just because it was on the original code and he might want it to be assignment rather then comparison operator.